# PHP + Allow Upload JPG Files

Tags: php, jpeg

I have some php code checking the type of files that users upload:

```
  $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
  $allowedFileTypes = array('image/jpeg','image/gif','image/png','image/jpg');
  if(!in_array($fileType, $allowedFileTypes)) {echo 'fileTypeNotAllowed'; exit;}
```

I find gif & png files upload without triggering the echo but jpg files trigger the echo.

below is an example of a file that triggers the echo:

[image]

Any advise on what I'm doing wrong here?

thx

Comment: echo $fileType when uploading the jpeg see what it says

Comment: Maybe your code won't allow beach photos

Comment: What does $fileType contains? `echo 'fileTypeNotAllowed: '.$fileType;`

Comment: Try adding `image/JPEG`, `image/pjpeg` (for IE), `image/x-png` (for IE).

Comment: Try using `!in_array(strtolower($fileType, $allowedFileTypes))`. `in_array` is case sensitive.

Comment: Baylor Rae seems right except a small mistake in code so try mine to check,
Try using `!in_array(strtolower($fileType), $allowedFileTypes)`

Comment: I wonder if there's consensus here (what the beach?).

Comment: yes it was the beach... lol... got it working strtolower fixed it and I've also added the extra file types... used the echo fileType to see the problem. thankyou so much...

Comment: `it was the beach` `strtolower fixed it` `added the extra file types` `used the echo fileType` I love it when there's a collaborative solution on SO!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you want to check what they are uploading... So I would use !in_array(strtlower($fileType, $allowedFileTypes)) in_array.

That should clear everything up.